# update multiple elements in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document with nested aggregations and I would like to set the all the attributes full to true. I have tried several methods using $set, but I am not able to update it.
How can this be achieved?

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b4347734e69052e544da67e"),
"providerId" : ObjectId("5b4242b9d8ff1b0020daab34"),
"aggregations" : [ 
    {
        "startTime" : "2012-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "endTime" : "2012-03-01T00:00:00Z",
        "quantity" : 0,
        "full" : false
    }, 
    {
        "startTime" : "2012-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "endTime" : "2012-03-01T00:00:00Z",
        "quantity" : 0,
        "full" : false
    }
],
"__v" : 0
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [`$[] The all positional`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) operator which updates multiple documents inside the array

```
db.collection.update(
  { },
  { "$set": { "aggregations.$[].full": true }}
)
```

and if you want to increment then

```
db.collection.update(
  { "aggregations.full": false },
  { "$inc": { "aggregations.$.quantity": 2 }}
)
```

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. What if the first full attribute is true, and the second full atttribute is false and I want to increment the quantity attribute for the one that is false

Comment: @RicardoMartin please check the answer

Comment: The increment does not work as I expected because it increments both.

Comment: @RicardoMartin check the updated one... It will increment the first one only... And please ask a new question If you have new doubt because you above query has been resolved thanks!!!