# update multiple elements in array mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to update chargeList isDelete property to true when date is greater than a specific value. my schema as follows.

```
{
   "chargeList": [
     { 
         "date": ISODate("2013-06-26T18:57:30.012Z"),
         "price": "123",
         "isDelete": false

     },
     { 
         "date": ISODate("2013-06-27T18:57:30.012Z"),
         "price": "75",
         "isDelete": false

     }
   ]
 }
```

schema is as follows.

```
var ChargeListSchema= new Schema({
    date:  { type: Date , default: Date.now  },
    price: { type: String, required: false },
    isDelete: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});

var ScheduleChargeSchema = new Schema({

  chargeList:[ChargeListSchema]


  });
```

I have tried as following code but it only update the matching first element in chargeList array.

```
 Model.update(
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "chargeList": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "date": {
           $gt:  ISODate("2013-06-26T18:57:30.012Z")
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": { "chargeList.$.isDelete": true }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`$[] all positional operator`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/)  to update multiple elements in an array

```
Model.update(
  { "_id": 1, "chargeList.date": { "$gt":  ISODate("2013-06-26T18:57:30.012Z") }},
  { "$set": { "chargeList.$[].isDelete": true } }
)
```

Comment: that doesnot update anyone of record.

Comment: It does work ... Please check your conditions there... Or post your schema...

Comment: added the schema to the post.

Comment: and my mongoose version is 4.11.6.

Comment: @ManojSanjeewa what is your mongodb version?

Comment: mongodb version 3.6.3

Comment: @ManojSanjeewa It is working for me and it should work for you... Please check the conditions and criteria please...

Comment: @ManojSanjeewa Ok Do one thing remove your all the condition and criteria and try simply `Model.update(
  {
    "_id": 1
  },
  {
    "$set": { "chargeList.$[].isDelete": true }
  }
)`

Comment: remove the criteria to { "_id": 1 } still not working,  { "$set": { "chargeList.$.isDelete": true } }   is still working but updates only one.

Comment: Ok got it... Update your mongoose version to 5.x

Comment: cannot upgrade becuase the project' s some mongoose functionalities not compatible with new version.

Comment: Actually mongodb version 3.6 is not compatible with mongoose 4.x you have to upgrade in order to use $[] positional operator and I think all functions of 4.x are available with 5.x... So don't worry

Comment: are you sure is it version problem? what is the workaround for the previose versions.

Comment: You can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244687/update-multiple-elements-in-an-array/51244726#51244726 and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206841/update-multiple-elements-in-an-array-in-mongodb/51208305#51208305